# How to make sure multiple threads run methods from different classes in order?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am making a program where a server offers a quiz to any number of clients. I have to make this using sockets, so I am trying to solve this by making multiple threads with socket objects in my server class, each socket maintaining the connection to one client.

This was working fine until I did some refactoring, after which I discovered through debugging that information between client and server was being sent in the right order by sheer luck.

Here is the code for my client threads. It's an inner class of my `Server` class and the `questionList` is an attribute thereof.

```
private class ClientThread implements AutoCloseable, Runnable
{
    private Socket clientConnection;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private DataInputStream input;

    public ClientThread(Socket clientConnection) throws IOException
    {
        this.clientConnection = clientConnection;
        output = new DataOutputStream(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new DataInputStream(clientConnection.getInputStream());
    }

    public void sendQuestion() throws IOException
    {
        if (input.available() > 0) if (input.readBoolean())
        {
            Question question = questionList.get((int) (Math.random() * questionList.size()));
            sendQuestionInfo(question);
        }
    }

    private void sendQuestionInfo(Question question) throws IOException
    {
        sendInfo(question.getAuthor());
        sendInfo(question.getTitle());
    }

    private void sendInfo(String info) throws IOException
    {
        output.writeUTF(info);
        output.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            sendQuestion();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {...}
}
```

And here is the relevant code from my `Client` class:

```
public class QuizClient implements AutoCloseable
{
    private Socket serverConnection;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private DataInputStream input;

    public QuizClient(String serverAdress, int portNumber) throws IOException
    {
        serverConnection = new Socket(serverAdress, portNumber);
        output = new DataOutputStream(serverConnection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new DataInputStream(serverConnection.getInputStream());
    }

    public void getQuiz()
    {...}

    private void playQuiz(boolean firstRun, Scanner scanner) throws IOException
    {...}

    private boolean playQuizTurn(Scanner scanner) throws IOException
    {...}

    private boolean isFirstRun()
    {...}

    private void askQuestion(Scanner scanner) throws IOException
    {
        output.writeBoolean(true);
        output.flush();
        Question question = getQuestion();
        question.quizMe(scanner);
    }

    private Question getQuestion() throws IOException
    {
        String author = input.readUTF();
        String title = input.readUTF();
        return new Question(author, title);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {...}
}
```

The intended order of execution is `askQuestion() -> sendQuestion() ->  getQuestion()`, but with the current code it insteads runs like `sendQuestion() -> askQuestion() -> getQuestion()`, and the program ends up being unresponsive.

How can I get this under control?

Comment: This answer requires an enormous answer, explaining various parallel computing paradigms, traps and pitfalls. I recommend reading some [literature](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/multithreading-in-java/), especially the [tag:Java] doc on [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: maybe ditch threads and go back to lock-in-step?

Comment: running things *in order* means *serialized* which is the **opposite** of concurrent. use a single thread. as this is worded now this is **off topic: too broad**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You can't avoid two concurrent processes if a client and a server are running on different machines.  The issue is synchronizing those concurrent processes, which is a legitimate issue.  As my answer illustrates, the problem the poster could be answered in three lines, so it was far from two broad.  Upvoted and voted to keep open.

Comment: @WarrenDew - you are conflating `concurrent` with `asynchronous`; they are **not the same thing**, the question is about concurrent processes on the same server, `threads` on the server in this case. the question clearly states *by making multiple threads with socket objects in my server class,* Unfortunately it does **not show** where the threads are created or how they are managed.

Comment: @WarrenDew - read what I wrote for comprehension, your attempt at an answer also demonstrates you did not read the question for comprehension either.

Comment: It seems my question has been a bit more convoluted than I thought, I apologize about that. Either way, I have solved the issue with methods running in the wrong order by introducing a lock and a condition, changing the first line of  `sendQuestion()` to `while (!(input.available() > 0)) condition.await();` and making a thread dedicated solely to signal the condition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your server's `ClientThread.sendQuestion()` method exits silently if `input.available()` is 0 - that is,  if the "true" has not yet been received from the client - which will often be the case with a newly established client.  Try having it wait patiently until there is data available, and see if you get any further.